# Copy Paste one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I've seen answers to this questions that are variations of what I'm looking for but when I attempt to modify the code to my situation, I keep getting error messages.

I have two workbooks, a Master "Template" and a monthly report for YTDJune2015. Each has 15 sheets which are the same for both, and I want to copy data from the monthly report into the Template which has formulas to calculate additional data for each of the 15 unique Sheets. I keep getting an error that there is a "type mismatch" so I haven't been able to test if the copy and pasting of individual sheets works. So far the code I have is:

```
'Sub ExtractData()


Dim SheetNames As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("C8:AB117").Select
FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Filter (*.xlsx),*.xslx", Title:="Open File(s)", MultiSelect:=True)

For i = 1 To UBound(FileNames)
Workbooks.Open FileNames
Sheets("Total").Range("C8:AB117").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Template.xlsm").Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=False

'Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
'Sheets("Domestic").Range("C8:AB117").Select
'Selection.Copy
'Windows("Template.xlsm").Activate
'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=False'
```

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending an array when a string is expected:

Change

```
Workbooks.Open FileNames
```

To

```
Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
```